# R will not open (R 3.6.3 binary for OS X 10.11)

Tags: r, load, cpu

I recently downloaded R 3.6.3 binary for OS X 10.11 to do some data analysis for my undergraduate  physics lab.

I input a column of my data from excel (there were 250,000 data points) and used 'scan()'. I didn't really know what it was going to do, but it wasn't what I wanted. So I tried to stop the command, it wouldn't stop. So I force quit the application.

When I tried to re-open the application, my CPU load sky rocketed (computer slowed down) and R wouldn't open.

I've already tried restarting my computer and re-installing the application.

If you know what I can do to get the application to work please let me know.

Comment: Are you running it in RStudio or just R?

Comment: Try [resetting the state of RStudio](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200534577-Resetting-RStudio-Desktop-s-State). You can also remove the hidden [.RData](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/218417317-Where-RStudio-Server-stores-data) file.

Comment: I was running just R.